# обрезать изображение при сохранении

Tags: php, изображения, symfony4, edit

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Services;
use App\Form\ServicesType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class CreateServiceController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/create/service", name="create_service")
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $service = new Services();
        $form = $this->createForm(ServicesType::class, $service);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $service = $form->getData();
            $service->setCreated(new \DateTime('now'));

            /** @var UploadedFile $imagereFile */
            $imageFile = $form->get('image')->getData();

            if ($imageFile) {
                $originalFilename = pathinfo($imageFile->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $safeFilename = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [^A-Za-z0-9_] remove; Lower()', $originalFilename);
                $newFilename = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$imageFile->guessExtension();

                // Move the file to the directory where brochures are stored
                try {
                    $imageFile->move(
                        $this->getParameter('image_directory'),
                        $newFilename
                    );
                } catch (FileException $e) {
                    // ... handle exception if something happens during file upload
                }

                // updates the 'brochureFilename' property to store the PDF file name
                // instead of its contents
                $service->setImage($newFilename);
            }

            // ... perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
            // for example, if Task is a Doctrine entity, save it!
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($service);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('services');
        }

        return $this->render('update_service/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

понимаю что файл сохраняется тут

```
try {
    $imageFile->move(
    $this->getParameter('image_directory'),
    $newFilename
  );
}
```

А вот задача. 
Прилетать будет картинка, я хочу чтоб картинка которая прилетала перед созранением обрбатывалась -  подогналась под определённую высоту и ширину, кропить всё что вылазить и потом аж только сохранить. Может кто подсказать как решить данную задачу?

В базе данных я храню имя картинки и в отображении дёргаю имя и подставляю путь и так отображаю катинику через asset

Боюсь делать через JS потому как:
1) не понимаю как получить данные с инпута обработать их и положить обратно (если делать до отправик формы)
2) если делать после отправки формы при отображении кортинки не очень нравить идея постоянно обрезать в JS одну и туже картинку сотню раз при том она будет занимать на жёстком диске кучу места.

Comment: http://image.intervention.io/ с помощью данной библиотеки можете делать что угодно с изображением. Ну либо вот идущая по умолчанию в php библиотека https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php

Comment: вот бы понять как это делаеться, по скольку если я просто пытаюсь сделать 
$imageFile = imagecrop($imageFile, ['x' => 0, 'y' => 0, 'width' => 100, 'height' => 100]);
то получаю ошибку
Attempted to call function "imagecrop" from namespace "App\Controller".

Comment: Потому что пространство имён у функций языка не то которые Вы используете в файлах, поэтому надо вызывать их из корня. Укажите \ рядом с функцией  `\imagecrop`

Comment: Attempted to call function "imagecrop" from the global namespace.
Я понимаю суть ошибки но не знаю как сделать правильно чтоб заработало, как дёрнуть от туда от куда надо

Comment: понял, спасибо небыла подключена библитека

Answer (score 0):

помогло с коментариев переключение пространства имён и подключения GD модуля